# What is the meaning of life according to Judaism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

I've heard different things, like improving your middot, etc.

Is there an agreed upon meaning to life in Judaism?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60545/759

Comment: I realised after, sorry